# Child theme style.css didn't work properly but the Customize Additional CSS did

Tags: functions, css

I just create TwentySeventeen Child Theme using Wordpress Codex instruction and re-align my site branding with some code. It work but after that I try to style a custom navigation menu with style.css and nothing happen.

I think there are problems with my child theme because when I added the CSS direct on Child Theme Additional CSS, its work.

I have follow this tutorial for custom navigation menu.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/

Please help me in this case, I have search various topic and still can't recognize the problem.

Sorry for my bad grammar and please bear with me if I make any mistake as this is my first time ask question on stackexchange. Thank a lot.

Comment: did you try using the chrome tools to see if your CSS is being overwritten?

Comment: @David Lee: I inspect the element and my CSS when using style.css didn't overwritten. For more details, I display the custom menu by adding php code to the header.php. Is it the reason why style.css didn't work?

Comment: @David Lee: By the way, thanks very much as the first person answer my question. xD

Comment: can you check in the resources if your style.css file is being loaded?

Comment: I missing one closing bracket in style.css and it's the culprit. I wish I can vote for your kindness support but didn't know how to do it. Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: np, i am here to help, good to know you fixed your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your stylesheet is not loading. In a child theme you should have a file called functions.php which enqueues your styles. If you aren't enqueuing your CSS then if you view your source you will not see that file being called.